# What shortcut keys can perform the actions in the diagram?

Tags: r, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-plugin

[image]

> Image Credit: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6632-r-language-for-intellij

- **IDE**: PyCharm;
- **Plugin**: R Language for IntelliJ;
- **Language**: R

PyCharm is great! I used it not only to write Python code, but also to write R scripts, after I installed the plugin.

**But, What shortcut keys can perform the actions in the diagram:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyboard shortcut `Alt+Ctrl+V` refactoring to introduce a variable.

[image]